# Issue with thread safe queue manifests as no output in IDE's console

Tags: c, multithreading, thread-safety, pthreads, posix

For a project I'm currently working on, I require a queue that can be used across multiple threads, taking this as an opportunity to learn more about pthreads I wrote the code I present below(without error checking / functions irrelevant to this question).  The code run's as expected in a terminal, however it does provides no output in my IDE (clion) which leads me to believe that there may be an issue lying somewhere in the code as I encountered an issue earlier that prevented output in the IDE's console while working as expected in the terminal.  If it does help, the previous issue I had was not unlocking the mutex when returning early from Queue_push.  Any help in identifying the issue would be greatly appreciated, thank you for your time.

```
struct queue
{
    QueueItem *first;
    QueueItem *last;
    pthread_mutex_t queueMutex;
    pthread_cond_t isEmptyCondition;
    bool isEmpty;
};

void Queue_push(Queue *queue, void *element)
{
    QueueItem *item;
    QueueItem_create(&item);
    item->value = element;

    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->queueMutex);
    if(queue->isEmpty == true)
    {
        queue->last  = item;
        queue->first = item;
        queue->isEmpty = false;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->queueMutex);
        pthread_cond_broadcast(&queue->isEmptyCondition);
        return;
    }

    queue->last->next = item;
    queue->last = item;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->queueMutex);
}

void *Queue_pop(Queue *queue)
{
    pthread_mutex_lock(&queue->queueMutex);

    while(queue->isEmpty == true) {
        pthread_cond_wait(&queue->isEmptyCondition, &queue->queueMutex);
    }

    QueueItem *item = queue->first;

    if(item == queue->last)
    {
        queue->isEmpty = true;
        queue->last = NULL;
    }

    queue->first = item->next;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&queue->queueMutex);
    return item->value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see several problems:

1. do you need the `isEmpty`? does `length==0` means empty? That cause some problem because in `Queue_pop` method you decrease the length without checking whether the queue is empty at that time, which will lead to inconsistence between isEmpty and length.
2. In your code below, if item is queue->last. you will set last to NULL. But the following line  `queue->first = item->next` will set queue->first=NULL->next, which will cause your program crash.

   ```
   if(item == queue->last)
   {
       queue->isEmpty = true;
       queue->last = NULL;
   }

   queue->first = item->next;
   ```

   3. you didn't release any dynamically allocated space.

Comment: 1. length is an artifact of debugging, it shall be removed later as I will not need to know the length of the queue, furthermore, I read that when using `pthread_cond_wait` a boolean test should be used, that is why isEmpty exists.  Is this not correct?

2 + 3. These are non issues, as my question stated I have not posted all of my code, only that which is relevant to the issue I am having.  Error checks, checks for null, and deallocations would only serve to lengthen the code.  As far as I know, please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: OK. I got it. so you are not using the length at all.

Comment: Correct, it was merely there for debugging purposes